# How to create a space between cards using bootstrap in React while mapping description of cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, mapping

Right now all the cards are aligned in a row but my goal is to create a small space between them.

I'm trying to create a fake Skateboarding eCommerce website. I started with the bearings (the part that goes inside the skateboard wheel to help it rotate). I successfully added all the cards to the page but find manipulating margin on the card with "m-1" using bootstrap adds a margin to the right side of the page for some reason and takes away some of the space that should be used up by the card.

```
enter code here

import React from 'react';
import { Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import bearingsData from './Product/bearingsData';




const Bearings = () => {

    
    return (
        <div className="main">
           <div className="title">
                <h1>Bearings</h1>
            </div>

            
            <div className="container " >
            <div className="row">     

            { bearingsData.map(product => {
                return (

                <Card className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-4 "  key={ product.id }>
                    <Card.Img src={ product.image }/>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>
                            { product.brand }
                        </Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text>
                            { product.name }
                        </Card.Text>
                        <Button> Add to Shopping Cart</Button>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>    
                );           
            })}            
            </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

export default Bearings;

Comment: Consider looking at using Flex? Bootstrap has classes for these documented here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/ 

Specifically adding a `justify-content: space-around;` or `d-flex justify-content-around` className might be what you are looking for.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't solve, doesn't seem to have an effect on it although other manipulation methods do, so its not to do with not implementing the name improperly. The only other thing I've managed to do is place cards on top of each-other in a column but nothing else I've tried will allow for the flex property ( I just added a div element inside the .map function with className="container d-flex justify-content-around mb-2"). otherwise the code in the description aligns them in a flex-like fashion but I can't get space between cards without also have the margin on the right be effected